# What caches can be cleared, when wanting to keep settings?

Tags: settings, cache

I do not know enough about the original purpose of the different caches. If I do a cleanup in a few months and clear many app cache items, is it safe for me to assume that most programs will not lose `settings`, if I clear the "cache" cache and leave the data cache alone?

*Most programs* means if a few lose settings, it is not a problem. There are many settings in many programs that took me quite some time to setup (and test).

By `settings`, I am referring to the applications own settings, not web settings, or settings that the application has access to. Take a game, for example. I do not care if the game is reset, levels are lost, or log-in is gone. But the `settings` for that game app must stay.  In a program, I do not care if it loses its thumbnails, and add-in parts, just that the `settings` for the program stay the same.

If this is all wrong, and programs are not normally supposed to use the data cache for settings, then tell me about it. I just assumed after losing some carefully selected settings that it is there in the data cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any cache can be cleared. Clearing the cache will not remove app settings.

Read more from this closed question in StackOverflow (should be migrated here):
[What's the difference between clear cache & clear data in android settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744104/whats-the-difference-between-clear-cache-clear-data-in-android-settings)

Comment: Ok thanks, I wrote that wrong.  The item is "clear Data" , not "data cache" oops, it is found in the same area.

Comment: @Psycogeek: Unlike clear cache, the Clear data is not always safe to clear, unless you're willing to lose potentially important settings. Some apps actually store their settings in an external server, and for those type of apps, once you relogin, they can restore their settings. You'll need to research individual apps to find out whether they do that.

Answer (score 2):

All memory caches are safe to be cleared, as they need to be designed as such since Android will clear them when memory get's tight.

Caches stored to disc will include things saved. However, most applications either save to file or utilise an sqlite database. These can be backed up with a file manager e.g. es explorer and an sqlite manager e.g. the one with the white db logo on a red background.

Clearing the cache will not corrupt the program itself. You will only lose saved data, such as the examples you mentioned; saved levels, hall of fame entries, badges, etc.

PS. @Psycogeek: Psycho is spelled with an h ;-)